# How do i select part of my array for a css border?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I need to create a border around each of these three contacts, So three borders in total. I am using angular/Typescript. I have to insert the border code into a css file within my project. Thanks!

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Contact } from '../models/contact';

 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })

  export class ContactsService {
  contacts: Contact[] = [
   { 
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    phoneNumber: '1234567890',
    email: 'John.Doe@example.com'
  },
 {
    firstName: 'Killiam',
    lastName: 'Jones',
    phoneNumber: '0987654321',
    email: 'Killiam.Jones@example.com'
  },
 {
   firstName: 'Emma',
   lastName: 'Swan',
   phoneNumber: '35715948620',
   email: 'Emma.Swan@example.com'
 }
 ];
 constructor() {}
 }
```

Comment: You must be painting these arrays in your view. So, ideally you will need to apply Css on DOM elements.

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari Not sure what you mean? It would be easy if i could select each of those contacts and assign a new class or id to them but i cant. Can you show me the correct syntax?

Comment: See the following answer, if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code snippet. I meant this.

```
 <style>
    .contact-detail {
       border: solid 1px red;
    }
    </style>
     <div *ngFor="let contact of contacts" class="contact-detail">
        {{contact.firstName}}
        {{contact.lastName}}......
     </div>
```

Comment: OH! Great idea didnt think of that. I did this snippet. Suprisingly it worked since it had commas between each of the arrays      p {
background-color: tomato;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
}

Comment: Hi..@SethVanHaelst, not sure if your question is being answered or you need more help?